# Overwriting dockercompose.yml with docker-compose.prod.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I hope this is an easy one and will help some more people since I could not find a straight answer to this.

I am following this example: 
https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#different-environments

**I have two files:**

**Docker compose for development**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  restapi:
    build: "./something/"
  db:
    image: postgres:10.5-alpine
volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
```

**Docker compose for production (docker.compose.prod.yml):**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  restapi:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/...
    restart: always
  db:
    restart: always
```

I the docker documentation it says:

> In the case of build and image, when using version 1 of the Compose
>   file format, using one option in the local service causes Compose to
>   discard the other option if it was defined in the original service.

Yet, when I try to run the docker-compose on my server, I fails because the build path does not exist, which means the entry was not overwritten.
**What is the problem?**

This commands fails:

```
sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d
```

With:

```
build path /.../.../.../.../... either does not exist, is not accessible, or is not a valid URL.
```

Comment: I've edited the answer once I saw the problem.

Comment: `when using version 1 of the Compose file format`... you are using version `3.7`, thus this statement does not apply in your case

Answer (score 1):

You can specify multiple `docker-compose` config files, which will override each other from right to left.

In the following example, prod.yml will override dev.yml.

```
docker-compose -f /path/to/docker-compose-a.yml -f /path/to/docker-compose-b.yml up.
```

SO, to solve your issue, I would do the following.

create 3 .yml files,

- common - will be the base for both environments.
- prod - will be prod only
- dev - will be dev only (will hold the build-path)

then to run dev environment: (common.yml + dev.yml)

```
docker-compose -f /path/to/docker-compose-common.yml -f /path/to/docker-compose-dev.yml up.
```

and production (common.yml + prod.yml):

```
docker-compose -f /path/to/docker-compose-common.yml -f /path/to/docker-compose-prod.yml up.
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. But except for the seperation in three files, this is exactly what I am doing. I don't see how this solves docker trying to access the build path over the image (which is my problem).

Comment: Also a trick is to create a symbolic link named `docker-compose.override.yml` which target the `docker-compose.prod.yml`. This way you can just use the `docker-compose` command without having to use the `-f` option

Comment: @Xen_mar the third file makes all the difference. the problem is that the build path specified in the dev.yml is not existing in the production environment, so you want it only to exist on the dev.yml file, and not in the common and production which will prevent the issue from occurring.